# Change Python Try/Catch Time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception

Currently, I am using this code:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Fitment").click()
except:
    payload.append('')
else:
    payload.append((driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fitment']")).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

My problem is that it takes much to long to wait for Python. I want to simply change the time until the exception is called. I have looked at signals and alarms but would prefer try/catch. If there is a better way I would like to know!

Comment: What exactly takes too long?

Comment: To be honest, if speed is the most important aspect of your program, you shouldn't be writing it in python....

Comment: Are you using Selenium here? I.e. using Python to pilot a browser via remote control? Sorry, but that is inherently slow. It's fine for testing, but is usually not the best way to navigate Web content. But you're not going to do any better in any other language, because it's the remote control process that's expensive.

Comment: I do not mean speed is my number one goal. I know Selenium is slow. I am grabbing data from a list of pages. Some of the pages have more data than others - no way to distinguish. I must capture all data so i always have to check if it exists if it doesn't it throws an error. I just want to reduce the amount of time python waits for `try` call to throw an exception. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried just accessing the pages directly rather than through a browser? That doesn't always work (especially with dynamic sites) but when it does, it's a lot faster.

Comment: I'll paraphrase @JonathanEunice: You are not waiting for Python, rather Python is waiting for Selenium.

Comment: @JonathanEunice I realize this But isn't python the one who sets how long it will wait for any given code block in a Try/Catch ? Is there a better way to check if a element exists?

Comment: @fr1tz What is the fastest way to see if a element exists in python?

Comment: @AWood I'm sure there's an internal timeout setting somewhere in the Python side of the driver. But the underlying browser interaction takes as long it requires, and no more. If you're not going to wait for at least that long, then just remove all your code and call it done. There's no point saying "do this!" and then aborting before it has a chance to do it. You might as well never have asked it to do anything in the first place.

Comment: @JonathanEunice The problem is not aborting early - It is always loaded quickly - some pages just simple do not have certain elements. I just need a way to check if they exist.

Comment: @AWood The page may load reasonably quickly. The time for interaction is not just the load time, but that plus time needed to communicate through the (large) Selenium software stack. I've used it on Python and JavaScript, and no where is it a fast process. You can try a different kind of interaction, such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) or [lxml](http://lxml.de). lxml is very fast at detecting elements, if speed is your primary goal. But, it won't ever have Selenium's or PhantomJS's "in the browser" context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `driver.implicitly_wait(0)`